# using an existing token as a variable in a custom token

Tags: database, tokens, emails

I am using simplenews to send out a newsletter.  I have a custom module.  It has a table that relates a user code to the user's email.

```
email_address                  user_code
bob.loblaw@lawblogs.com        37XylT12
```

In the simplenews email I will send, the idea is that each user will receive a link with their usercode in it (i.e., http://www.domain.com/?q=go&c=37XylT12).

I've been attempting to create a custom token to place in the text of the newsletter and replaced with my custom link prior to send.  However, I have two issues: 1) I cannot find an example of a token that includes a db_select query to return data and 2) I cannot find a way to access the simplenews email token ([simplenews-subscriber:mail]) in my custom module -- I need this value to lookup the code.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.
KMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the database to set a token is not different from accessing the database in other cases.

```
function mymodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $sanitize = !empty($options['sanitize']);

  $replacements = array();

  if ($type == 'YOUR TOKEN TYPE') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'YOUR TOKEN':
          $replacements[$original] = /* CODE TO QUERY THE DATABASE */;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

As for accessing the value of a token defined from a module, when you know the token you are looking for, you can call [token_replace()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7) passing the token for which you want to know the value as first parameter. Keep in mind that your implementation of `hook_tokens()` is going to be called again; be careful of not causing a loop.

Comment: I've completed the database component and it is working with string values I type in, however, I'm struggling with the token_replace() function.  The token I'm trying to replace is below -- $text = token_replace('[simplenews-subscriber:mail]');  If I return $text to the page, it is correct.  However, if i try to use the value in php, it is [simplenews-subscriber:mail].  Please advise.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. In your code, you need to use $text as value of the token.

Comment: It was an issue I ran into calling a token from another module.  In the module, the variable $subscriber was set within the module.  The token_replace() call needed me to submit the variable of $subscriber, but I could not.  I ended up adding a custom token to the module in a separate, custom tokens.inc file.  It's not perfect, but it works.  Thanks for your help!